# npm install now always throws errno EACCES error

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

when I install anything with npm (e.g. `npm i json-stream`)

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stream failed, reason: connect EACCES 104.16.25.35:443 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/maxfowler/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stream failed, reason: connect EACCES 104.16.25.35:443 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/maxfowler/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:310:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
npm ERR!   type: 'system',
npm ERR!   errno: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/maxfowler/.npm/_logs/2020-05-04T10_18_22_396Z-debug.log
```

I'm using nvm on mac OS 10.14. I've tried running the command as sudo and in different working directories. Any ideas?

I've also tried `ping 104.16.25.35` (which works) and `ping 104.16.25.35:443` which returns `ping: cannot resolve 104.16.25.35:443: Unknown host`

Comment: even after completely uninstalling node and nvm then reinstalling nvm for my user, I still get the same error

however, on a different mac user on my same computer, I installed nvm, and it is working... so I still don't know what the issue could be on my user account

Comment: hmm its back to not working on my other mac user again now, same error.

Answer (score 0):

try to install it in super user mode add sudo in command like sudo npm i json-stream

Answer (score 0):

This is happening when you install node or npm with sudo. I think you are using nvm with sudo ? Which is IMO a bad idea. A solution could be re-`chown` you nvm and subfolders to you user and or re-install without sudo with clear of the `/Users/maxfowler/.nvm/` folder. I'm assuming this one belong to root user.

In another hand, if you need a one shot execute of `json-stream` I recommand to use the `npx` call as `npx json-stream`. This way you aren't installing anything on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

I found that my ~/.npmrc file had permissions 600. I deleted this file, and then it seems everything is working again.

I'm not 100% sure this was what fixed it, but it seems so. My .nvm and .npm directories otherwise had the correct permissions and that was not the issue.

Comment: can confirm does not fix error.